# How to return NULL if binary searched number is not in index?

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, search, binary

I am writing a code, which is essentially finished with one major problem. I have written a binary search function, returning the found index. Whenever I run my code and search for any power of 2, it works properly. However, whenever I input any other number, such as 50, it returns an error.

At the end of my code I have an else statement saying if none of the other statements return a value to return NULL, so I am having a bit of trouble. Thanks. I am running on Xcode, and also UNIX server, but I commented out lines that run off the UNIX server.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    int* search(int* begin, int* end, int needle);
    int main(int argc, char **argv) { //int argc = 1, char **argv array of char pointers
        int num = 0;
        int nums[10], i;
        int *found = NULL;
        if(argc != 2) {
            printf("Enter a number to a power of 2 to search for:\n");
            scanf("%d" , &num);
        }
       // num = atoi(argv[1]);
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // initialzes array by shifting binary code to the left adding powers of 2
            nums[i] = 1 << i; }
        found = search(nums, &nums[9], num);
        if(found) {
            printf("Number %d found in index %ld.\n", num, found - nums);
                 }
        else {
            printf("Number %d was not found.\n", num);
       }
        return 0;
    }
int* search(int* begin, int* end, int needle){
    int *middle = (end-begin)/2 + begin;
    if(*middle == needle){
        return middle;
    }
    else if(needle < *middle){
        end = middle;
        return search(begin, end-1, needle);
    }
    else if(needle > *middle)
    {
        begin = middle;
        return search(begin+1, end, needle);
    }
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

I want the else statement in the main() function to execute whenever a value searched for is not in the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is there is no base case for your recursion

Think about it this way: your needle will always be bigger or smaller than the middle if the number is not in the array

Meaning it will never reach the last else, it will always happen to recurse incrementing or decrementing until it tries to dereference gibberish, hence the segmentation fault

What you need is to add the old good base case to your binary search like so:

```
int* search(int* begin, int* end, int needle) {
    int *middle = (end-begin)/2 + begin;

    if(begin == end) {
        //recursion ends when there are no more segments to divide in two
        //so after your final single element segment, a decrement or increment will happen
        //making your end and begin pointers the same 
        return NULL;
    }
    else if(*middle == needle) {
        return middle;
    }
    else if(needle < *middle) {
        end = middle;
        return search(begin, end-1, needle);
    }
    else if(needle > *middle) {
        begin = middle;
        return search(begin+1, end, needle);
    }   
}
```

Comment: This code actually did not work. However, you gave me insight to figure out the code that would. If I utilize your if statement: if(begin == end), I am not checking the correct index fields. I had to use this if statement to get my code to execute: if(begin+1 == end-1) return NULL; maybe you can further explain why? Also, my first code was wrong. In the 2nd else if, it should be begin -1 and the second else if should be end+1. Thanks for your input.

Comment: The code **does** work. I've compiled it and tested it myself. And no, you dont need to add begin -1 and end +1. Also, I did explain why